# (Search Bar) how to display data after user type the search bar?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

for now my code is displayed the list of data after i open the page, how to hide the data and only show it when user type the searchbar

```
filterList(evt) {
    this.initializeItems();

    const searchTerm = evt.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }
    this.users = this.users.filter(currentUser => {
      if (currentUser.name && searchTerm) {
        if (currentUser.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is the html file

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  showCancelButton (ionInput)="filterList($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users"> 
  <ion-avatar>
    <img src="{{user.images}}">
  </ion-avatar> &nbsp;
  <ion-label>{{user.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: put a [hidden] on your <ion-list> ie. [hidden]="!searchTerm"

Comment: @jae.phoenix but after i clear the text all of data is show up how to fix it

Comment: put searchterm == ''

Comment: @jae.phoenix let's make these responses an answer. Answers can be short.

Comment: @jae.phoenix put it where? sorry newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show or hide something we can add the `[hidden]` property onto our element, like so:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  showCancelButton (ionInput)="filterList($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list [hidden]="!searchTerm" >
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users"> 
  <ion-avatar>
    <img src="{{user.images}}">
  </ion-avatar> &nbsp;
  <ion-label>{{user.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This will then show or hide your list based on the value of `searchTerm`.
If it has no value, the list is hidden. And if there is a value, the list is visible.

**EDIT**

Take a look at this stackBlitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-df8ecx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: its not work now the list displayed everytime the tabs opened

Comment: I don't know if you copied my code directly, but I made a spelling error on the [hidden] property.  It was 'searchtem', fixed it now to say 'searchTerm'.

Comment: ya, if i add ==' ' data displayed everytime page loaded

Comment: I added a demo.  Please take a look there